# Call two JavaScript functions from one button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick

I'm trying to execute two separate functions from one onClick.

It is a dictionary service which returns definitions from Glosbi API and the second function is Google Maps API call that changes the map to what has been searched for.

The first functions works perfectly, but the second function calling Google Maps API doesn't work.

Can anyone see anything in my code that isn't right or needs to be changed? I feel very close!

```
function codeTerm() {
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $('#term').focus(function(){
            var full = $("#definition").has("definition").length ? true : false;
            if(full === false){
                $('#definition').empty();
            }
        });

        var getDefinition = function(){
            var word = $('#term').val();

            if(word === ''){
                $('#definition').html("<h2 class='loading'>We haven't forgotten to validate the form! Please enter a word.</h2>");
            }
            else {
                $('#definition').html("<h2 class='loading'>Your definition is on its way!</h2>");
                $.getJSON("http://glosbe.com/gapi/translate?from=eng&dest=eng&format=json&phrase=" +word+ "&pretty=true&callback=?", function(json) {
                    if (json !== "No definition has been found."){
                        var meanings = "";
                        json["tuc"].forEach(function(tuc) {
                            if (typeof tuc["meanings"] !== 'undefined') {
                                tuc["meanings"].forEach(function(m) {
                                    meanings += "<p>"+m["text"]+"</p>\n";
                                }); 
                            }
                        });

                        $("#definition").html(meanings);
                    } 
                    else {
                        $.getJSON("http://glosbe.com/gapi/translate?from=eng&dest=eng&format=json&phrase=&pretty=true" + "?callback=?", function(json) {
                            console.log(json);
                            $('#definition').html('<h2 class="loading">Nothing found.</h2><img id="thedefinition" src=' + json.definition[0].image.url + ' />');
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
            return false;
        };

        $('#search').click(getDefinition);
        $('#term').keyup(function(event){
            if(event.keyCode === 13){
                getDefinition();
            }
        });
    });
}

var geocoder;
var map;

function initialize() {
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 8,
        center: latlng
    }

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
}

function codeAddress() {
    var country = document.getElementById('search').value;
    geocoder.geocode( { 'search': country}, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: results[0].geometry.location
            });
        } else {
            alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
        }
    });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

$('#search').click(country);
$('#term').keyup(function(results){
    if(results.keyCode === 13){
       country();
    }
});
```

And the HTML

```
<head>

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta name="author" content="Matthew Hughes">
    <meta name="Dictionary" content="A dictionary web service">
    <title>Dictionary Web Application</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="dictionary.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" /> 
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCVD1Kaf1yE4M9IcBNRAyujObcY2sGI0J0&sensor=false"></script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
    <script src="dictionary.js"></script>



</head>

<body>

    <div id="container">

        <div id="top">

            <header>

                <h1>Dictionary Application</h1>

            </header>

        </div>

        <div id="app">

            <div id="panel">

                <input id="term" type="text" placeholder="Enter a word...">
                <button id="search" onclick="codeTerm(); codeAddress();">Define!</button>


            </div>

        <section id="definition">

        </section>

              <div id="map-canvas">

              </div>

        </div>



        <footer>

            <p>Created by Matthew Hughes</p>

        </footer>

    </div>

</body>
```

Thanks!

Comment: did you check the javascript console for any errors?

Comment: Define "doesn't work."  The title and beginning of the question imply that the second function isn't being invoked at all, is that the case?  Or is it being invoked and something else is failing?  When you step through this in a debugger, what happens?

Comment: in what way doesn't it work?  does the call not get made?  doesn't return a 200?  are you checking for errors in the console?

Comment: In my console I have 'google' is not define and 'country' is not defined.

Comment: I can js.fiddle if need be

Comment: Any reason why you're including `dictionary.js` twice?

Comment: Just a stupid mistake, my bad, but that isn't the problem :(

Answer (score 0):

In the comments you mention 2 errors...

> google is not defined

Was the inclusion of the Google API successful?  You have this:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCVD1Kaf1yE4M9IcBNRAyujObcY2sGI0J0&sensor=false"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
```

Do those references work?  In your browser debugging tools, take a look at the network tab.  What do these calls return, if anything?  It sounds like the API isn't being loaded successfully.  Do you need those to be `https` specifically?  Try omitting the protocol so that it defaults to the current page's protocol:

```
<script src="//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCVD1Kaf1yE4M9IcBNRAyujObcY2sGI0J0&sensor=false"></script>
<script src="//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
```

You're also including one of your JavaScript libraries twice:

```
<script src="dictionary.js"></script>
```

That *might not* break anything, but it also *might*.  In any event, it should only be included once.

---

> country if not defined

You create a variable called `country` in one of your functions:

```
function codeAddress() {
    var country = document.getElementById('search').value;
    // other code
}
```

So it's scope is within that function only.  But you also try to reference it outside of that function, and you try to reference it *as a function*:

```
$('#search').click(country);
$('#term').keyup(function(results){
    if(results.keyCode === 13){
       country();
    }
});
```

So even if it were moved to a global scope, `country` isn't a function so it's not clear what you're trying to accomplish with these two handlers.  Maybe you meant to invoke a different function?

Comment: You'll have to excuse my bad JavaScript, this is my first time creating a project with JavaScript and using Api's. I've removed the duplicate libraries and api url's.

Comment: I don't know what needs to be included in the bottom part for the .click, I was trying to use the previous one from the first function to help myself!

Comment: @omgched: In both cases (the `.click()` and inside the `if` statement) you're looking to call a function, but there's no function called `country`.  You have functions like `codeTerm` and `getDefinition`, for example.  Did you mean to invoke one of those functions?  Or, if you're looking to do something else, you'd need to write a function that does it and invoke that.  (Though I recommend not using the same name as a variable, that could make things confusing in some scopes.)